# Secondary indexes on composite keys in cassandra

Tags: go, cassandra

I have this table in cassandra

```
CREATE TABLE global_product_highlights (
  deal_id text,
  product_id text,
  highlight_strength double,
  category_id text,
  creation_date timestamp,
  rank int,
  PRIMARY KEY (deal_id, product_id, highlight_strength)
)
```

When i fire below query in Golang

```
err = session.Query("select product_id from global_product_highlights where category_id=? order by highlight_strength DESC",default_category).Scan(&prodId_array)
```

I get ERROR : ORDER BY with 2ndary indexes is not supported.

I have an index on category_id.

I don't completely understand how is secondary index applied on composite keys in cassandra.

Appreciate if anyone would explain and rectify this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ORDER BY` clause in Cassandra only works on your first clustering column (2nd column in the primary key), which in this case is your product_id.  [This DataStax doc](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/select_r.html) states that:

> Querying compound primary keys and sorting results ORDER BY clauses
>   can select a single column only. That column has to be the second
>   column in a compound PRIMARY KEY.

So, if you want to have your table sorted by highlight_strength, then you'll need to make that field the first clustering column.